# vue-i18n output using as quasar data-table title value

Tags: laravel, ecmascript-6, vue.js, quasar, vue-i18n

### Two ways to combine vue-i18n with quasar-framework in vue

I need to know, how to put the `$t('message.hello')` function, what is actually in a `v-html` or in double bracets `{{ $t('message.hello')` in a variable.
I tried to return the function in the `computed:`-, and `mounted()` instances, I also tried to put it in a `window.var`.

### <del>The other variant</del>

<del>And the other way round, I need to put in `vue` rendered variables into the `$t('message.hello', {scope: 'world'})` method like that way: `$t('message.hello', {scope: 'returned.fromDataOrSomewhere'})`</del>

### Why do I need this

1. I have to inject some data from `promise` in the `vue-i18n` to translate dynamic values.
2. I need to put the translated values in a [Quasar](http://quasar-framework.org/components/datatable.html)  `<q-datatable>` which columns are configured as below:

   ```
   {
     label: 'ID', //here I need a variable instead of string
     field: 'id',
     filter: true,
     sort: true,
     type: 'number',
     width: '10%'
   },
   {
     label: 'Username', //here too - and so on...
     field: 'username',
     filter: true,
     sort: true,
     type: 'date',
     width: '20%'
   },
   ```

### EDIT:

Second case is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like a true reactivity, you need pass to **q-table** component a v-bind:columns using a computed property. If you use a data is not reactivity.

```
<q-table
  ...
  :columns="columnsI18n"
  ... 

<script>
. . .
computed: {
    columnsI18n () {
      let columns = [
        {
          name: 'username',
          required: true,
          label: this.$t('mailboxes.label'),  // Translation
          align: 'left',
          field: row => row.domain,
          format: val => `${val}`,
          sortable: true
        },
        {
          name: 'active',
          align: 'center',
          label: this.$t('domains.active'), // Translation
          field: row => row.active,
          format: val => String(!!val),
          sortable: true
        }
      ]
      return columns
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go with  `this` in `js`.
Because this is inside a vue-instance and it's `this`-bind.
thats why you have to go like this:

```
{
  label: this.$tc('message.textA', 1),
  field: 'id',
  filter: true,
  sort: true,
  type: 'number',
  width: '10%'
},
{
  label: this.$tc('message.textB', 1),
  field: 'username',
  filter: true,
  sort: true,
  type: 'date',
  width: '20%'
},
```